# Octave Symbolic Error- "Error in var export"

Tags: octave

I am having a tough time with the symbolic package in octave.

Software Versions (downloaded everything today):

-Octave: 4.0.0

-OctSymPy 2.2.2

-Python: 3.4

-SymPy: 0.7.6

When I try to multiply/divide/raise to a power symbolic variables, I get the following error:

PYTHON: Error in var export

Resetting the octsympy communication mechanism

Closing the Python pipe...

error: python_cmd: unexpected return

error: called from
    python_cmd at line 143 column 6
    mtimes at line 42 column 5

```
syms X Y

X*Y
```

I am totally stumped. Does anyone have any ideas on the cause of this? I can add and differientiate symbolic expressions, so it is working to some extent.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you run python and use sympy directly? For example "sympy import *
 x, y = symbols ("x y") x*y" ? I suspect this is a problem with sympy and/or python

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I just have downloaded and installed the python version 2.7.11 and worked fine.
Ah, don't forget to reinstall SimPy, but this time on the new Python version.
When you get back to octave, it'll recognize that version.